# Quarkus Hibernate ORM - import.sql not executed

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I use Quarkus Devservices to spinup postgres db for test purposes.

As also mentioned at https://quarkus.io/blog/hibernate-orm-config-profiles/ I set generation to `drop-and-create` and created import.sql file which must be used to create db tables from scratch every time the app is started, however, nothing is created, instead I get odd error messages which don't fit to the status of the postgres db.

```
2022-03-12 13:43:29,851 WARN  [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (JPA Startup Thread: <default>) SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
2022-03-12 13:43:29,852 WARN  [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (JPA Startup Thread: <default>) relation "filepart" does not exist, skipping
2022-03-12 13:43:29,853 WARN  [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (JPA Startup Thread: <default>) SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
2022-03-12 13:43:29,854 WARN  [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (JPA Startup Thread: <default>) table "download" does not exist, skipping
2022-03-12 13:43:29,855 WARN  [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (JPA Startup Thread: <default>) SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
2022-03-12 13:43:29,855 WARN  [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (JPA Startup Thread: <default>) table "filepart" does not exist, skipping
2022-03-12 13:43:29,867 WARN  [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (JPA Startup Thread: <default>) SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 42P07
2022-03-12 13:43:29,867 WARN  [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (JPA Startup Thread: <default>) relation "download" already exists, skipping
2022-03-12 13:43:29,868 WARN  [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (JPA Startup Thread: <default>) SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 42P07
2022-03-12 13:43:29,868 WARN  [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (JPA Startup Thread: <default>) relation "filepart" already exists, skipping
2022-03-12 13:43:51,035 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) quarkus-resteasy-postgres 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 2.7.4.Final) started in 27.125s. Listening on: http://localhost:8080
```

appliction.properties:

```
quarkus.datasource.devservices.enabled=true
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.devservices.port=5432
quarkus.datasource.username=postgres
quarkus.datasource.password=postgres

quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=drop-and-create
# it is default, only explicit to be clear:
quarkus.hibernate-orm.sql-load-script=import.sql
```

Complete project is here:
https://github.com/syr/quarkus-resteasy-postgres/tree/hibernate_drop_not_working

UPDATE: when disabling db generation by

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=none
```

SQL, which is obviously generated from the entities is still executed, whereas import.sql is ignored.

```
create table Download (idProperty1 varchar(255) not null, idProperty2 varchar(255) not null, finished boolean, id int8, primary key (idProperty1, idProperty2));
create table FilePart (id int8 not null, filePartFilePath varchar(255), idProperty1 varchar(255), idProperty2 varchar(255), primary key (id));
alter table if exists FilePart add constraint FKia6okjgd7yxo21sfga0hej3ni foreign key (idProperty1, idProperty2) references Download;
```

Answer (score 4):

Please refer to the guide at https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#quarkus-hibernate-orm_quarkus.hibernate-orm.scripts-database-scripts-related-configuration

The property "quarkus.hibernate-orm.sql-load-script" is used for loading the data (insert statements primarily).

For DDL (Create and Drop tables), you might have to use the properties below:

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.scripts.generation=drop-and-create
quarkus.hibernate-orm.scripts.generation.create-target=create.sql
quarkus.hibernate-orm.scripts.generation.drop-target=drop.sq
```

Answer (score 0):

The import.sql is invoked when there is a schema change like a new table created. Hence, it only runs when you change the database generation to drop-and-create.

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.scripts.generation=drop-and-create
```

After DB is initialized, you can change the database generation setting back to update

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.scripts.generation=update
```